# Oracle Database Audit table AUD$ moving to other than system tablespace is supported by Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle12c, audit-trail, audit-tables

`AUD$` table holds all the database audit information in Oracle Database. And by default it resides in `SYSTEM` tablespace.

From research I know that using `DBMS_AUDIT_MGMT`, it is possible to move the  `AUD$` table to the other tablespace.

My question is, whether or not it is supported by Oracle? 
And will there be any issues if I move the `AUD$` table out of `SYSTEM` tablespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. (see Doc ID 1328239.1 f from Oracle Support)